# Cannot create a new Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am running Ruby -v 2.2.0

Everytime I run the `rails new` or `rails -v` I get an error that reads:

```
rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.2.0
```

I was running Ruby 2.1.5 but just switched to 2.2.0 because of the error message. Now that I switched I am still getting the same error message. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: What is the output of  `which ruby` ?  And `rbenv versions` ?  From the command line.

Comment: I see rvm tagged, but aren't you using rbenv ?

Comment: Is `ruby -v` showing `2.2.0` ? If yes is there rails listed in `gem list` ?

Comment: Did you install rails with 'gem install rails'?

Comment: It's possible will be a problem of PATH ? rails -v in installation directory working well ? Are you on Linux ? Have you used root to doing installation ?

Comment: my Ruby -v is 2.1.5, (when I switch to 2.2.0 I get the same error) my rbenv -v is 0.4.0, rails is in my gem list, i ran 'gem install rails', my PATH is correct, I'm Mac OSX -v 10.9.2. rails is installed in my root. Rails was working the day before, then the following day  I got this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every installed ruby version have separate set of gems.

This rbenv message says that `rails` gem installed only in `2.2.0` version but currently rbenv set to use some another version.

You can list of available rbenv commands by `rbenv` command in terminal. There are some useful of them which may help to solve this question:

- `rbenv versions` will display all installed ruby versions (and show asterisk with currently selected version).
- `rbenv global 2.2.0` will set global Ruby version.
- `rbenv local 2.2.0` will set Ruby version for current folder only.
- `rbenv shell 2.2.0` will set Ruby for current shell session only.

Comment: Yeah but when I switch to version 2.2.0 and run the same command I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that proper version of Ruby not installed. Install it and Bundle:

```
rvm install 2.2.0
bundle install
```